# How do I track recursion depth?

Tags: c++

I have a recursive function that I am troubleshooting.  I want to output the recursion depth...i.e. how many times the function calls itself.

If I use a static variable that increments at the top of the function and decrements at the bottom.

Will this accurately give me the depth level?

```
recurse()
  {
  static int depth = 0;
  depth++;
  /*
  do stuff
  recurse()
  */
  depth--;
  return return_value;
  }
```

Comment: Try and see. (It's obviously not thread-safe, just so you know.)

Comment: Empirical evidence will be wrong here.

Comment: thanks for all the answers...i will update and post shortly

Comment: This is why $DEITY gave us debuggers.

Answer (score 11):

```
recurse(int depth = 0){
    ....
    recurse(depth+1);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To make it easier and

- *exception* safer
- *thread* safer
- supporting [tree recursion](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/chapter1/node13.html) (!)

<sub>If you really stretch your imagination, this could make it easier for the compiler to inline some recursive calls, and/or perform tail-call optimization in case of tail recursion. *I have no evidence that this plays a role*, but I can imagine referencing external symbols from within a function body influencing compiler optimization.</sub>

I suggest:

```
stuff recurse(int level=0)
{

     //...
     recurse(level+1);

     //... (return stuff?)
     //... (throw exceptions?)

     //...
     recurse(level+1);

     //... (return stuff?)

}
```

Comment: I think his original plan would have also worked for tree recursion

Comment: @MooingDuck You're right. I'm used to thinking in async/push-pull contexts these days. (Imagine passing a a lambda callback to the nested invocation. The static depth would be seen as updated in the lambda. It's not a usual scenario, I guess :))

Answer (score 5):

No, it might not, if an exception is thrown.  A better (and more common) option is:

```
int recurse(int depth=0)
{
    recurse(depth+1)
    return return_value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do this non-intrusively you can actually ask your compiler to instrument every call for you, e.g. with gcc:

```
#include <iostream>
static __thread int depth=-1;
extern "C" {
    void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *, void *) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
    void __cyg_profile_func_exit (void *, void *) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
    void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *func,  void *caller)
    {
        depth++;
    }


    void __cyg_profile_func_exit (void *func, void *caller)
    {
        depth--;
    }
}

class Foo {
public:
    void bar() {
        std::cout << "bar: " << depth << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

You'll need to compile with `-finstrument-functions` for this to work.

Comment: This is very compiler specific and therefore non-portable code.

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to increment a depth variable that's defined outside of the recursive function for the purposes of thread safety and printing it from outside of that function.

Here's a simple factorial example demonstrating it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned factorial(unsigned x, unsigned* depth)
{
  if (x <= 1)
    return 1;

  ++*depth;

  return x * factorial(x - 1, depth);
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned depth, f;

  depth = 0; f = factorial(1, &depth);
  printf("factorial=%u, depth=%u\n", f, depth);

  depth = 0; f = factorial(2, &depth);
  printf("factorial=%u, depth=%u\n", f, depth);

  depth = 0; f = factorial(6, &depth);
  printf("factorial=%u, depth=%u\n", f, depth);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\>recdep.exe
factorial=1, depth=0
factorial=2, depth=1
factorial=720, depth=5
```

Answer (score -1):

In a single threaded context it will work.

Answer (score -2):

yes, it should work. i dont see any problems with that.