# c recursion too deep

Tags: c, recursion

As an example, I'll be using code, close to that, [posted on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829319/how-do-i-track-recursion-depth):

```
void recurse(int level=1) {
    printf("Level=%02d\n", level);

    if (level > 14) {
        printf("Depth exceeded 14 !!!\n");
        return;
    }
    recurse(level+1);
    //recurse(level+1);//commented out, i get levels 1-15 in a row
}
```

Suppose i call it with

```
recurse(1);
```

With one recurse call inside function i get what i expected - levels 1-15 printed out and excess message.

If i uncomment the second call, im getting not 2 x 15 excess messages, but im guessing, 15 x 15 depth excess messages.

Is there a way to rewrite this in a way that i would have 2 x 15 recursion depths, not 15 x 15 ?

Thank you guys for quick answers.

Unfortunately, i have had it all wrong :) I was under impression, that the first inside call would recurse out, then the second one, so i would have 2 x 15 depths.

Comment: Wrong guess. You'll get 2^14 messages, as you can easily verify (or prove by induction).

Comment: `void recurse(int level=1) {` :syntax error (C does not have default arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the function as is. Call it twice.

```
recurse(1);
recurse(1);
```

Comment: No, this generates 2 * 15... these aren't recursive calls, they are from outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
void recurse(int level=1) {
    printf("Level=%02d\n", level);

    if (level == 1)
    {
       recurse(2);
       printf("Level=%02d\n", level);    
    }

    if (level > 14) {
        printf("Depth exceeded 14 !!!\n");
        return;
    }
    recurse(level+1);
}
```

You can do it in a single function but it's nearly the same to call resurse(1) twice !

If it can help's you...

Comment: thanks for answer, ill be rethinking this whole recursion idea.