# React generic table-like component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, recursion

I am trying to create a component that can create a table-like experience with any given array of objects and if this object has an array inside, it will render its children in a expandable section. It will happen to any level of deepness.

I managed to develop the recursive function that renders the elements and I can apply click function on the first level.

The problem is that when I am some levels deep I dont know who it belongs to.

Any idea to write a function that can detect what level I am and set a property show=true and render the tree again ?

Thanks.

Example:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

let keys = [
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e',
  'f',
  'g',
  'h',
  'filhos',
  'netos',
  'bisnetos',
];

function Example() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      index: 1,
      show: true,
      a: '1st item',
      b: '2nd item',
      c: '3rd item',
      d: '4th item',
      filhos: [
        {
          index: 1,
          show: false,
          a: 'filho 1st item',
          b: 'filho 2nd item',
          c: 'filho 3rd item',
          d: 'filho 4th item',
          netos: [
            {
              index: 1,
              show: false,
              a: 'neto 1st item',
              b: 'neto 2nd item',
              c: 'neto 3rd item',
              d: 'neto 4th item',
              bisnetos: [
                {
                  index: 1,
                  show: false,
                  a: 'bisneto 1st item',
                  b: 'bisneto 2nd item',
                  c: 'bisneto 3rd item',
                  d: 'bisneto 4th item',
                  f: 'bisneto 5th item',
                  g: 'bisneto 6th item',
                  h: 'bisneto last item',
                },
              ],
              f: 'neto 5th item',
              g: 'neto 6th item',
              h: 'neto last item',
            },
          ],
          f: 'filho 5th item',
          g: 'filho 6th item',
          h: 'filho last item',
        },
      ],
      f: '5th item',
      g: '6th item',
      h: 'last item',
    },
    {
      index: 2,
      show: true,
      a: '1st item',
      b: '2nd item',
      c: '3rd item',
      d: '4th item',
      filhos: [
        {
          index: 1,
          show: false,
          a: 'filho 1st item',
          b: 'filho 2nd item',
          c: 'filho 3rd item',
          d: 'filho 4th item',
          netos: [
            {
              index: 1,
              show: false,
              a: 'neto 1st item',
              b: 'neto 2nd item',
              c: 'neto 3rd item',
              d: 'neto 4th item',
              bisnetos: [
                {
                  index: 1,
                  show: false,
                  a: 'bisneto 1st item',
                  b: 'bisneto 2nd item',
                  c: 'bisneto 3rd item',
                  d: 'bisneto 4th item',
                  f: 'bisneto 5th item',
                  g: 'bisneto 6th item',
                  h: 'bisneto last item',
                },
              ],
              f: 'neto 5th item',
              g: 'neto 6th item',
              h: 'neto last item',
            },
          ],
          f: 'filho 5th item',
          g: 'filho 6th item',
          h: 'filho last item',
        },
      ],
      f: '5th item',
      g: '6th item',
      h: 'last item',
    },
    {
      index: 3,
      show: true,
      a: '1st item',
      b: '2nd item',
      c: '3rd item',
      d: '4th item',
      filhos: [
        {
          index: 1,
          show: false,
          a: 'filho 1st item',
          b: 'filho 2nd item',
          c: 'filho 3rd item',
          d: 'filho 4th item',
          netos: [
            {
              index: 1,
              show: false,
              a: 'neto 1st item',
              b: 'neto 2nd item',
              c: 'neto 3rd item',
              d: 'neto 4th item',
              bisnetos: [
                {
                  index: 1,
                  show: false,
                  a: 'bisneto 1st item',
                  b: 'bisneto 2nd item',
                  c: 'bisneto 3rd item',
                  d: 'bisneto 4th item',
                  f: 'bisneto 5th item',
                  g: 'bisneto 6th item',
                  h: 'bisneto last item',
                },
              ],
              f: 'neto 5th item',
              g: 'neto 6th item',
              h: 'neto last item',
            },
          ],
          f: 'filho 5th item',
          g: 'filho 6th item',
          h: 'filho last item',
        },
      ],
      f: '5th item',
      g: '6th item',
      h: 'last item',
    },
  ]);

  const expandLine = (currItem) => {
  
    setData(data.map((x) => {
      if (x.index === currItem.index) {
        let newValue = currItem;
  
        for (const item of Object.entries(currItem)) {
          const key = item[0];
          const value = item[1];
  
          if (value instanceof Array) {
            newValue = {
              ...currItem,
              [`${key}`]: value.map((z) => ({ ...z, show: true })),
            };
          }
        }
  
        return newValue;
      }
  
      return x;
    }));
  
    console.log(data);
  };
  
 function renderer(arr, tempArr = [], counter = 0) {
    counter++;
    return arr.map((currItem, key) => {
      return keys.map((key, y) => {
        const inner = currItem[key];
  
        if (inner instanceof Array) {
          tempArr = inner;
        }
  
        if (inner && !(inner instanceof Array)) {
          return (
            <p style={{}} onClick={() => expandLine(currItem)} className={currItem.show ? 'show' : ''} show={currItem.show}>
              {Array(counter).fill('_').toString().replaceAll(',','')} {inner}
            </p>
          );
        }
  
        if (y === keys.length - 1) {
          if (tempArr.length > 0) {
            return renderer(tempArr, [], counter);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
  
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(7, 1fr)',
        margin: '10px',
      }}
    >
      <h1 style={{ border: '1px solid black', margin: 0 }}>First</h1>
      <h1 style={{ border: '1px solid black', margin: 0 }}>Second</h1>
      <h1 style={{ border: '1px solid black', margin: 0 }}>Thrid</h1>
      <h1 style={{ border: '1px solid black', margin: 0 }}>Fourth</h1>
      <h1 style={{ border: '1px solid black', margin: 0 }}>fifth</h1>
      <h1 style={{ border: '1px solid black', margin: 0 }}>sixth</h1>
      <h1 style={{ border: '1px solid black', margin: 0 }}>seventh</h1>
      {renderer(data)}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <Example />, document.getElementById('root') );
```

```css
p {
   order: 1px solid black;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: green;
}

.show {
  background-color: blue;
}

#root, #other-div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<div id="other-div"></div>
```

Comment: I believe this may duplicate [How do I track recursion depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829319/how-do-i-track-recursion-depth) - you may find an answer there.  If that post does _not_ answer your question, please explain how your question differs from the linked post.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thank you for your reply. I think in my case I know the deepness of the tree with the counter property I set. what I would like to understand is, when I click on the item, how to find it looping initial array.

Lets say I am in tree levels deep, how do I loop over the array to find it and then change a property that will re-render the page and reflect the change? 

does that makes sense? thanks!